# I obtain an error when using grouped_ggbetweenstats

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggstatsplot

I have some issues with the function grouped_ggbetweenstats from ggstatsplot package. I have tried with different data, but I always obtain the same error:

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() puede ser aplicada solamente a vectores
```

I provide an example here:

```
lapply(c("rstatix", "ggstatsplot", "openintro"), require, character.only = TRUE)
print(hsb2)
grouped_ggbetweenstats(data = hsb2, x=prog, y= math, grouping.var = gender, results.subtitle=F, messages=F, var.equal=T, p.adjust.method="holm")
```

Please, could anyone provide any idea about what the error is and a possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can use the data I provided. `hsb2` . You can find them as part of `openintro` package.

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get the error. Did you try with a restart and use `library` instead of `require`?

Comment: I never thought that was the problem. I have tried `library` and it works perfectly. 
Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Great to hear it solved your problem!